# I can't understand how the number of people grows in this problem (exponentially, linearly, etc)

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

Could someone tell me how does N grows in this problem (and how to code it)?

A family tree starts with the marriage of x and y, and they have two children. Two of these children get married, and one remains single. In this peculiar family, the same formula repeats itself every time. Everyone has three children, two of them get married and one remains single. Write a function that determines the number of people in the tree at the time the Nth generation gets married. (including spouses)

- x and y's children are the first generation

This is what I tried:

```
def generations(n):
    people = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        generation = i * 2 - 1
        people += generation
    return people
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i * 2 - 1 is a linear equation and isn't actually an accurate read on generations of people.

This sounds like a homework problem. As such, think about it as 2 people have 3 kids, 2 get married (5 in that generation by marriage), That generation has 2 families that have 3 children (6) 4 get married (10 by marriage in this gen). Next gen: 4 families have children giving (12) marriage -> 20... ect. I'm assuming you need to find an equation to model this.

Answer (score 0):

```
P(0) = 2
P(1) = 2P(0) + 1
P(2) = 4P(0) + 2
P(3) = 8P(0) + 4
P(4) = 16P(0) + 8
...
P(N) = (2**N)P(0) + 2**N-1
P(N) = (2**N-1)(2P(0) + 1)
P(N) = (2**N-1)(5)
so the total number of people is:
P(0) + P(1) + P(2) ... + P(N) = 2 + 5 ( (2 ** N) - 1)
```

The function for your question is 5 ((2 ** N) - 1) + 2, and it is not linear. It is actually exponential.

You can check it out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_4_%2B_8_%2B_%E2%8B%AF for a better understanding in the math part.